# (rails) how does one correctly link to a javascript file in a rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Is there a helper of some sort? I want to make a javascript file, put it in the rails directories somewhere, and have the file be included in a view so I can use the methods and functions I declare in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
```

With jquery.js in public/javascripts